# why do I get Runtime Error(SIGABRT) while submitting this code in codechef?

Tags: c++

This codes executes successfully when I run it on my system 
but it gets a runtime error(Runtime Error(SIGABRT)) when I submit the code on codechef.

Here's a link to the question http://www.codechef.com/problems/LELUCKYN

What is this error and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for ( auto i = 1; i <= t; i++ ) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<int> vec(n);
        for ( auto in = 0; in < n; in++ ) {
            int input;
            cin >> input;
            vec[in] = input;
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < vec.size(); x++ ) {
            for ( int y = x; y < vec.size(); y++ ) {
                string num="";
                for (int z = x; z <= y; z++ ) {
                    num.append(to_string(vec[z]));
                }
                int number = stoi(num);
                int c4 = 0, c7 = 0;
                while ( number != 0 ) {
                    int d = number % 10;
                    if ( d == 4) c4++;
                    else if (d ==7 ) c7++;
                    number/= 10;
                }
                int po = (int)pow( c4, c7 );
                if (c4 != 2 && c7 != 2 && po <= ( ( y - x ) + 1 )) count++;
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What input did you try?

Comment: reformatted to make this to make it almost readable.  It still needs to be reduced; author needs to go through different parts and see minimalize the code.  what is not working, etc.

also try to summarize a small gist of what is needed from the codechef page; you shouldnt rely on folks having to go onto another site to help you. the problem should be self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, you're concatenating all the numbers into a string, and then trying to convert that into an `int` in order to count the digits.

That string will not always be convertible to `int` because it would be too large, and `stoi` throws an exception in that case.

You can just count the digits in the resulting string (count `'4'`s and `'7'`s instead of `4`s and `7`s), *or* you can count the digits in each number and add them up, without going through a string conversion.

Comment: I did as you have told but now I get another message that my answer is wrong yet it compiles and runs successfully on my system..

Comment: @AyushChaurasia C4 and C7 can grow quite large - almost 900,000 in the worst case - so `pow` could quite possibly overflow. I believe you'll need to use maths to get rid of the `pow`.

Comment: Ok. So I wrote a separate function to calculate power and the code compiles and runs succcessfullly on my machine but on codechef it says wrong answer..